# Frequency of/if didUpdateLocations: called has different behavior if startUpdatingLocation called in init

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've noticed that there is a huge huge difference in the location behavior depending upon when startUpdatingLocation: is called - specifically if its called in a class's init property there's a couple of immediate initial calls made to didUpdateLocations and no more, whereas if startUpdatingLocation is called elsewhere there's multiple resulting calls to didUpdateLocations.

Here's example code for the init case:

```
- (id) init 
{
    ….
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

When I execute this code then my app gets a couple of calls to didUpdateLocations: and then doesn't get any more (tested with me walking about 100 meters back and forth).

However if I instead execute this code:

```
- (id) init 
{
    ….
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    //[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) someExternalTrigger
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then didUpdateLocations: gets called dozens of times even if the device is stationary, and it continues to get called numerous times as I walk about a few meters.
This is in complete contrast to if startUpdatingLocation: is called in init, one would think it ought to be the same behavior.

Does anybody have any explanation or speculation for why I am observing this?

**Edit** 
I additionally experimented changing the init to have this:

```
[self   [self performSelector:@selector(doStartLocationManager) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

And then I start getting multiple continuous updates.

Comment: What is calling someExternalTrigger?

Comment: It gets called in response to a push notification.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the behavior you're seeing, but kCLHeadingFilterNone is not an appropriate value for locationManager.distanceFilter. kCLHeadingFilterNone is intended to be used as a setting for locationManager.headingFilter.